# Prioritize certain rows where to versions exist

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a pricing table for users

```
pid | price | service | package | interval | user
1   | 1     | 1       | 10      | w        | 0
2   | 4     | 1       | 10      | m        | 0
3   | 3     | 1       | 10      | m        | 1
4   | 2     | 1       | 20      | w        | 0
5   | 8     | 1       | 20      | m        | 0
6   | 5     | 1       | 25      | w        | 0
7   | 20    | 1       | 25      | m        | 0
8   | 4     | 1       | 25      | w        | 1
9   | 4     | 1       | 15      | w        | 1
10  | 16    | 1       | 15      | m        | 1
```

rows with 0 hold general prices for everybody. Now I sometimes give discounts to certain users. This price will have a user's id as user.

Now I want a query that selects all prices for a user. It should take all prices where the user is 0 or where the user is the id of a user but if there is a row with 0 as user and the user id as user it should only take the row with the user id as user.

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE user = 0 OR user = 1 AND [...]
```

should return

```
pid | price | service | package | interval | user
1   | 1     | 1       | 10      | w        | 0
3   | 3     | 1       | 10      | m        | 1
4   | 2     | 1       | 20      | w        | 0
5   | 8     | 1       | 20      | m        | 0
7   | 20    | 1       | 25      | m        | 0
8   | 4     | 1       | 25      | w        | 1
9   | 4     | 1       | 15      | w        | 1
10  | 16    | 1       | 15      | m        | 1
```

Comment: What are the names of the columns that determine a duplicate for user = 0 and user != 0? Is it `service`, `package` and `interval`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it's service, package and interval but most of the time I'm giving the service with the query like `service = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `union all`.  First select all prices for the user.  Then select all prices from user 0 that don't match.  Your question is not clear about what the price is for.  Here is a guess:

```
select p.*
from prices p
where p.user = 1
union all
select p.*
from prices p
where p.user = 0 and not exists (select 1
                                 from prices p2
                                 where p2.service = p.service and
                                       p2.package = p.package and
                                       p2.interval = p.interval and
                                       p2.user = 1
                                );
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "what the price is for"? These are different prices a user can see on our website and it is used to get the right price for an order when a user places one.

Comment: @maddo7 . . . This assumes the price is for a service/package/interval combo.  That is not explicit in your question.

Comment: wouldn't the subquery need to be `select 1
                                 from prices p2
                                 where p2.service = p.service and
                                       p2.package = p.package and
                                       p2.interval = p.interval  and p2.user != 1` else the second query after union all would always return no results.